# How to use jq --seq correctly?

Tags: json, jq

I tested "jq --seq" with a very small file like this

```
jq --seq ".title, .id" test.json
```

test.json is this:

```
{"title": 3, "id":4}
{"title": 3, "id":4}
{"title": 3, "id":4}
```

And I got this error. And jq does not output anything but this error

```
ignoring parse error: Unfinished abandoned text at EOF at line 4, column 0
```

How do I use jq --seq correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--seq` format expects each value to be preceded with ASCII RS character (dec 30 / hex 1E)

> Use the `application/json-seq` MIME type scheme for separating JSON texts in jq’s input and output. This means that an ASCII RS (record separator) character is printed before each value on output and an ASCII LF (line feed) is printed after every output. Input JSON texts that fail to parse are ignored (but warned about), discarding all subsequent input until the next RS. This mode also parses the output of jq without the `--seq` option.

If you add these chars to the file, it works.

```
txt = <<~JSON
\x1e{"title": 1, "id":2}
\x1e{"title": 3, "id":4}
\x1e{"title": 5, "id":6}
JSON

File.write('test.json', txt)
```

Then

```
% jq --seq ".title, .id" test.json

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

---

But looks like you don't need this option at all? Taking your file (without the RS characters) and feeding it to `jq ".title, .id" test.json` yields the same results.